# Cubic equations $x^3-x^2+bx+c=0$ and $x^3+cx^2+bx-d=0$ have two common roots. Show $b^2=d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If the equation $x^3-x^2+bx+c=0$ and
>
> $x^3+cx^2+bx-d=0$ has $2$ roots common .
>
> Then show that $b^2=d.$

what i try

$x^3-x^2+bx+d=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)$

$\sum \alpha=1,\sum \alpha \beta=b,\alpha \beta \gamma=-c.$

$x^3+cx^2+bc+d=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\delta)$

$\sum \alpha=-c,\sum \alpha \beta=b,\alpha \beta \delta=-d.$

How do i solve it after that help me please

Comment: $\sum \alpha, \sum \alpha \beta$ are devoid of mathematical content.

Comment: Not so if c = -1.

Comment: The command of Mathematica Resolve[Implies[
  Exists[{x, y}, x != y, 
   x^3 - x^2 + b*x + c == 0 && x^3 + c*x^2 + b*x - d == 0 && 
    y^3 - y^2 + b*y + c == 0 && y^3 + c*y^2 + b*y - d == 0], 
  b^2 == d]] performs $c+1\neq 0\lor b^2-d=0\lor d-1\neq 0 .$ We see there are other relations too. The answer to your question is negative.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561593/condition-for-two-cubic-equations-to-have-two-common-roots

Answer (score 1):

$$x^3−x^2+bx+c=0 \tag{1}$$

$$x^3+cx^2+bx−d=0 \tag{2}$$

Note that $c+1\ne 0$ and $c+d\ne 0$, otherwise the two equations become identical (why?).

$(2)-(1)$,

$$(c+1)x^2=c+d \implies x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{c+d}{c+1}} \ne 0$$

which are the common roots.

$(2)\times c-(1)$,

$$(c+1)(x^2+b)x+c^2-d=0$$

To allow non-zero common solutions, viz., $x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{c+d}{c+1}}$ forcing

$$x^2+b=c^2-d=0$$

So
\begin{align}
  \frac{c+d}{c+1}+b &= 0 \tag{$x^2+b=0$} \\
  c &= -\frac{b+d}{b+1} \tag{$d\ne 1, b\ne -1$} \\
  d &=\left( -\frac{b+d}{b+1} \right)^2 \tag{$c^2-d=0$} \\
  (b+1)^2 d &= b^2+2bd+d^2 \\
  d^2-(1+b^2)d+b^2 &= 0 \\
  (d-1)(d-b^2) &=0 \\
  d &= b^2 \tag{reject $d=1$}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha$,  $\beta$ be the two common roots and $\gamma$, $\delta$ the different roots. Then,

$$\alpha\beta + (\alpha+\beta)\gamma = b,\>\>\>\>\>
\alpha\beta + (\alpha+\beta)\delta = b$$

Take the difference of the two equations to get

$$(\alpha+\beta)(\gamma-\delta)=0$$

which leads to $\alpha+\beta=0$ and $\alpha\beta=b$. Plug $\alpha+\beta$ into

$$\alpha+\beta + \gamma =1,\>\>\>\>\> \alpha+\beta + \delta =-c$$

to get $\gamma = 1$ and $\delta = -c$. Then, plug $\gamma$ and $\delta$ into,

$$\alpha\beta\gamma = -c,\>\>\>\>\>\alpha\beta\delta = d$$

to obtain

$$\alpha\beta=b=-c=-\frac dc$$

where the relationship $b=\alpha\beta$ derived earlier is used.  Eliminate $c$ to arrive at

$$b^2=d$$

Answer (score 0):

The code of Mathematica

```
Resolve[Exists[{x, y}, x^3 - x^2 + b*x + c == 0 && x^3 + c*x^2 + b*x - d == 0 && 
   y^3 - y^2 + b*y + c == 0 && y^3 + c*y^2 + b*y - d == 0]]
```

produces 
$$(b+1=0\land c-1=0\land d-1=0)\lor (c+1=0\land d-1=0)\lor \left(c+1\neq 0\land b+c=0\land c^2-d=0\right)\lor \left(b c+b+c+d\neq 0\land b^2 c^3+b^2 c^2 d+2 b^2 c^2+2 b^2 c d+b^2 c+b^2 d+2 b c^3+4 b c^2 d+2 b c^2+2 b c d^2+4 b c d+2 b d^2-c^5-c^4+2 c^3 d+c^3+5 c^2 d+2 c d^2+d^3-d^2=0\right) $$

Comment: @the downvoter: What is wrong in my answer? TIA.